# Error installing virtualenvwrapper virtualenvwrapper.sh location

Tags: python, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

I'm trying to install virtualenvwrapper on Mac 10.13.5 following the [instructions](https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html#basic-installation).

I ran

```
sudo pip install virtualenvwrapper
```

and added

```
export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs
export PROJECT_HOME=$HOME/Devel
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

to my shell file as [instructed](https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html#shell-startup-file).

However, running

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

just returns

```
/usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh: No such file or directory
```

I've read other questions here, but no proposed solution worked for me. Also tried running

`sudo pip uninstall virtualenvwrapper`

but got back

`Skipping virtualenvwrapper as it is not installed.`

Running `pip freeze` gets back (among other things)

```
pyparsing==2.0.1
python-dateutil==1.5
pytz==2013.7
scipy==0.13.0b1
six==1.4.1
virtualenv==16.0.0
xattr==0.6.4
zope.interface==4.1.1
```

but nothing related to virtualenvwrapper (`which virtualenvwrapper.sh` returns nothing as well).

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3):

are you sure you have virtualenvwrapper installed before running `sudo pip uninstall virtualenvwrapper`?

I'm on Mac 10.11.6

I did `pip3 install --user virtualenvwrapper`
and found my virtualenvwrapper.sh in `/Users/username/Library/Python/3.6/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue (only on Ubuntu 20.04).

In my case, `pip` installed it to `/home/USERNAME/.local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh`.

I changed that specific line in `.bashrc` to `source $HOME/.local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh` and it worked.